# React Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Name')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
function Edit() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
    const [id, setId] = useState('');
    let history = useNavigate();

    var index = Employees.map(function (e) {
        return e.id
    }).indexOf(id);

    const handleUpdate = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let a = Employees[index] ;
        a.Name  = name;  
        a.Address = address;
        history("/");
    }
```

Error display at line a.Name = name
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Name')

The error disappear but the data is not updated

if I add a new Object , I can edit but I can't update default data

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: What is `Employees`?  When the error occurs, what is the value of `index`?  What do you expect `Employees[index]` to be and why?

Comment: There's a good chance your `indexOf()` is returning `-1` because no match for `id` is found, resulting in an invalid index for the array access here: `Employees[index]`. But without a reproducing example of the issue we can't say for sure.

Comment: The program can found correct id with this code , I mean when I write new data and sumbit => this error occur

Comment: Employees is a object include {id, name, age, address, phone} , value of index is the index of Employee which needed to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Initially you set id as ''
2. Then you map over Employees, trying to find the item with indexOf(id)
3. Since it is '', it will probably return -1, since not found
4. let a = Employees[index] // Employees[-1] is undefined
5. a.Name  = name;   //undefined.Name
   a.Address = address; //undefined.Address

Comment: Thanks for answer but program can find id but can't update because undifined

Comment: What do you mean,  by "program can find the id"?. You set it as empty string, and I don't see anywhere you call setId to modify it.

Comment: at this line bro const [id, setId] = useState('');

Comment: Yes, I am saying, that you set it to empty string, and if your array has ids ['1', '2' ...].indexOf('') is -1

Comment: No id is not empty string but id = Emloyee[index]